# Lost focus event in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/V7uc7/

My requirement is that whenever user moves out of div# aaa, system should hide the same div element, which is happening.

However I have come across following issue.

Within a div element when user switch over between the text box is also triggering hide event.How to fix this issue.

Basically user steps out of div element , system should hide that div element .Also user should be allowed to switch over between the text box within that div element

```
<div id="aaa">
    <input type="textbox" name="a"/>
    <input type="textbox" name="b"/>
    <input type="textbox" name="c"/>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#aaa").focusout(function () {
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#aaa{
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    width:172px;
    height:133px;
    padding:32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $("#aaa input").blur(function () {
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#aaa").hide()
        }, 50);
    }).focus(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cBg52/)

Comment: Cool!  it is working.  Thanks Arun . Appreciated your help. Will accept your answer in next 5 min.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevent `focusout` event bubble up from your input to the parent div which will result in hiding your parent div:

```
$("#aaa input").focusout(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7uc7/1/)**

---

Based on your comment, you can use:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('#aaa')) {
        $('#aaa').hide();
    }
});

$("#aaa input").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7uc7/2/)**

Comment: This would mean that leaving the div from a textbox would not hide the div.

Comment: This will fix my issue but it fails to hide div element when user moves out of div element. Thanks anyways